# What is even use of Django Nested Atomic?

Tags: python, django, database, transactions

I recently came across nested atomic blocks in Django and it looks like even if error occurs in any of those blocks, all of them will be rollbacked. So, why do people use nested atomic block?

Specifically, what is the difference between

```
with transaction.atomic():
    do_something

    with transaction.atomic():
        do_something_more
```

and

```
with transaction.atomic():
    do_something

    do_something_more
```

?
If there is no overall difference, then in what scenario first should be used instead of second?

Comment: You can catch exception in outer block and then only inner block will be rolled back

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012071/django-nested-transactions-with-transaction-atomic